# Rename files recursively by adding them the folder's name and move them into another folder

Tags: windows, cmd, command

I have this:

```
>upperFolder
  >folder 0
    >file 0
    >file ...
    >file n
  >...
  >foldern
    >file 0
    >file ...
    >file n
```

...and I want this

```
>upperFolder
  >folder 0_file 0
  >folder 0_file ...
  >folder 0_file n
  >...
  >folder n_file 0
  >folder n_file ...
  >folder n_file n
```

For example:

I have this:

```
>Pictures
  >Wallpapers
    >Reaper
    >Skull
    >Night
  >Avatars
    >InuYasha
    >Battler
    >Valentino
```

...and I want this

```
>Pictures
  >Wallpapers_Reaper
  >Wallpapers_Skull
  >Wallpapers_Night
  >Avatars_InuYasha
  >Avatars_Battler
  >Avatars_Valentino
```

I need this for renaming big amounts of files in Windows cmd. It's getting hard to do it all manually. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to move files one level deep, then the following command will work from the command line:

```
for /d %D in (*) do @for %F in ("%D\*") do @move "%F" "%D_%~nxF" >nul
```

Double all percents if you want to run the command within a batch script.

If you truly want to move all files in the hierarchy to the parent folder in a recursive manner, then the following batch script will work:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%D in ('dir /b /s /ad *^|sort /r') do (
  pushd "%%D"
  for %%F in (*) do move "%%F" "..\%%~nxD_%%F" >nul
  popd
)
```

So a directory structure like

```
>Pictures
  moveFiles.bat
  pic1.jpg
  pic2.jpg
  >Avatars
    Battler.jpg
    InuYasha.jpg
    Valentino.jpg
  >Wallpapers
    pic1.jpg
    pic2.jpg
    >Nature
      Forest.jpg
      Ocean.jpg
    >Sports
      Baseball.jpg
      Basketball.jpg
      Football.jpg
```

Becomes:

```
>Pictures
  Avatars_Battler.jpg
  Avatars_InuYasha.jpg
  Avatars_Valentino.jpg
  moveFiles.bat
  pic1.jpg
  pic2.jpg
  Wallpapers_Nature_Forest.jpg
  Wallpapers_Nature_Ocean.jpg
  Wallpapers_pic1.jpg
  Wallpapers_pic2.jpg
  Wallpapers_Sports_Baseball.jpg
  Wallpapers_Sports_Basketball.jpg
  Wallpapers_Sports_Football.jpg
  >Avatars
  >Wallpapers
    >Nature
    >Sports
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, look at the output and remove the `echo` before `move`, if it is OK:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "startfolder=X:\path\upperFolder"
cd /d "%startfolder%"
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    for %%j in ("%%~i\*") do (
        if not exist "%startfolder%\%%~i_%%~nxj" (
        echo move "%%~fj" "%startfolder%\%%~i_%%~nxj"
        ) else echo ERROR: "%startfolder%\%%~i_%%~nxj" already exist.
    )
)
```

Input:

```
C:\UPPERFOLDER
├───Folder1
│       File11
│       File12
│       File13
│       File14
│       File15
│       File16
│       File17
│       File18
│       File19
│
├───Folder2
│       File21
│       File22
│       File23
│       File24
│       File25
│       File26
│       File27
│       File28
│       File29
│
├───Folder3
│       File31
│       File32
│       File33
│       File34
│       File35
│       File36
│       File37
│       File38
│       File39
│
├───Folder4
│       File41
│       File42
│       File43
│       File44
│       File45
│       File46
│       File47
│       File48
│       File49
│
├───Folder5
│       File51
│       File52
│       File53
│       File54
│       File55
│       File56
│       File57
│       File58
│       File59
│
├───Folder6
│       File61
│       File62
│       File63
│       File64
│       File65
│       File66
│       File67
│       File68
│       File69
│
├───Folder7
│       File71
│       File72
│       File73
│       File74
│       File75
│       File76
│       File77
│       File78
│       File79
│
├───Folder8
│       File81
│       File82
│       File83
│       File84
│       File85
│       File86
│       File87
│       File88
│       File89
│
└───Folder9
        File91
        File92
        File93
        File94
        File95
        File96
        File97
        File98
        File99
```

..output:

```
C:\UPPERFOLDER
│   Folder1_File11
│   Folder1_File12
│   Folder1_File13
│   Folder1_File14
│   Folder1_File15
│   Folder1_File16
│   Folder1_File17
│   Folder1_File18
│   Folder1_File19
│   Folder2_File21
│   Folder2_File22
│   Folder2_File23
│   Folder2_File24
│   Folder2_File25
│   Folder2_File26
│   Folder2_File27
│   Folder2_File28
│   Folder2_File29
│   Folder3_File31
│   Folder3_File32
│   Folder3_File33
│   Folder3_File34
│   Folder3_File35
│   Folder3_File36
│   Folder3_File37
│   Folder3_File38
│   Folder3_File39
│   Folder4_File41
│   Folder4_File42
│   Folder4_File43
│   Folder4_File44
│   Folder4_File45
│   Folder4_File46
│   Folder4_File47
│   Folder4_File48
│   Folder4_File49
│   Folder5_File51
│   Folder5_File52
│   Folder5_File53
│   Folder5_File54
│   Folder5_File55
│   Folder5_File56
│   Folder5_File57
│   Folder5_File58
│   Folder5_File59
│   Folder6_File61
│   Folder6_File62
│   Folder6_File63
│   Folder6_File64
│   Folder6_File65
│   Folder6_File66
│   Folder6_File67
│   Folder6_File68
│   Folder6_File69
│   Folder7_File71
│   Folder7_File72
│   Folder7_File73
│   Folder7_File74
│   Folder7_File75
│   Folder7_File76
│   Folder7_File77
│   Folder7_File78
│   Folder7_File79
│   Folder8_File81
│   Folder8_File82
│   Folder8_File83
│   Folder8_File84
│   Folder8_File85
│   Folder8_File86
│   Folder8_File87
│   Folder8_File88
│   Folder8_File89
│   Folder9_File91
│   Folder9_File92
│   Folder9_File93
│   Folder9_File94
│   Folder9_File95
│   Folder9_File96
│   Folder9_File97
│   Folder9_File98
│   Folder9_File99
│
├───Folder1
├───Folder2
├───Folder3
├───Folder4
├───Folder5
├───Folder6
├───Folder7
├───Folder8
└───Folder9
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit tricky on windows ;)

But you can do it the following way:

create 2 batch files outside the folder which should be "scanned"
first one should be named findfiles.bat

```
forfiles /p %1 /s /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE %~p0\renameit.bat @relpath @file %1 %~p0\"
```

the second one should be named renameit.bat

```
@echo off
set oldname=%1
set oldname=%oldname:.\=%
set oldname=%oldname:"=%
set tmpname=%2
set newname=%oldname:\=_%
set newname=%newname:"=%

move "%4%3\%oldname%" "%4%3\%newname%"
```

now you can execute the findfiles.bat with the main folder as parameter. (so in your example : Pictures)

So for example if your Pictures folder resides in D:\ then create the 2 batch files in D:\
then go to cmd and execute `findfiles.bat Pictures`

**But be careful! Try to execute this on a copy of your real folder first! I dont want to be the one who is responsible that you lost your photos or whatever ;)**

Only downside is that you will end up with empty folders where the files have been moved from, but i think this is something one could live with :)